# how to create various dummies based on consecutive values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following panel dataset. "winner" =1 if in period (date), someone is a winner, zero if loser.

```
ID   date  winner 
A   2017Q4  NaN
A   2018Q4   1         
A   2019Q4   0   
A   2020Q4   0    
A   2021Q4   1   
B   2017Q4  NaN 
B   2018Q4   1   
B   2019Q4   1   
B   2020Q4   0    
B   2021Q4   0   
C   2017Q4  NaN
C   2018Q4   0      
C   2019Q4   0    
C   2020Q4   0  
C   2021Q4   0 
D   2017Q4  NaN   
D   2018Q4   0                 
D   2019Q4   1   
D   2020Q4   1 
D   2021Q4   1
```

I want to create four dummy variables, WW =1 if someone is winner in two consecutive periods. LL=1 if loser in two consecutive periods. WL if winner in period 1 and loser the next period, and LW vice versa.

UPDATE

when i apply the answers below i get the following

```
ID   date  winner  WW  LL  WL  LW
A   2017Q4  NaN
A   2018Q4   1     0   0   0   0  
A   2019Q4   0     0   0   1   0    
A   2020Q4   0     0   1   0   0  
A   2021Q4   1     0   0   0   1
B   2017Q4  NaN
B   2018Q4   1     0   0   0   0   
B   2019Q4   1     1   0   0   0
B   2020Q4   0     0   0   1   0
B   2021Q4   0     0   1   0   0
C   2017Q4  NaN
C   2018Q4   0     0   0   0   0      
C   2019Q4   0     0   1   0   0
C   2020Q4   0     0   1   0   0
C   2021Q4   0     0   1   0   0
D   2017Q4  NaN
D   2018Q4   0     0   0   0   0                
D   2019Q4   1     0   0   0   1
D   2020Q4   1     1   0   0   0
D   2021Q4   1     1   0   0   0
```

How do i make sure I get the NaN when the previous value is NaN?
desired output

```
ID   date  winner  WW  LL  WL  LW
A   2017Q4  NaN
A   2018Q4   1    NaN NaN NaN NaN   
A   2019Q4   0     0   0   1   0    
A   2020Q4   0     0   1   0   0  
A   2021Q4   1     0   0   0   1
B   2017Q4  NaN
B   2018Q4   1    NaN NaN NaN NaN  
B   2019Q4   1     1   0   0   0
B   2020Q4   0     0   0   1   0
B   2021Q4   0     0   1   0   0
C   2017Q4  NaN
C   2018Q4   0    NaN NaN NaN NaN    
C   2019Q4   0     0   1   0   0
C   2020Q4   0     0   1   0   0
C   2021Q4   0     0   1   0   0
D   2017Q4  NaN
D   2018Q4   0    NaN NaN NaN NaN               
D   2019Q4   1     0   0   0   1
D   2020Q4   1     1   0   0   0
D   2021Q4   1     1   0   0   0
```

How to do this in the most simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `map` 1 and 0 to "W" and "L"
2. get the 2-period streak
3. `get_dummies` for the "streak"
4. `join` to original DataFrame ignoring the first row of each ID

```
wins = df["winner"].fillna(0).map({1:"W",0:"L"})
streaks = wins.shift() + wins
other = pd.get_dummies(streaks.where(df["ID"].eq(df["ID"].shift())))
output = df.join(other.where(df["ID"].duplicated()&df["winner"].shift().notna()))

>>> output

   ID    date  winner   LL   LW   WL   WW
0   A  2017Q4     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   A  2018Q4     1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   A  2019Q4     0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
3   A  2020Q4     0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4   A  2021Q4     1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
5   B  2017Q4     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6   B  2018Q4     1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7   B  2019Q4     1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
8   B  2020Q4     0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
9   B  2021Q4     0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
10  C  2017Q4     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
11  C  2018Q4     0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
12  C  2019Q4     0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
13  C  2020Q4     0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
14  C  2021Q4     0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
15  D  2017Q4     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
16  D  2018Q4     0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
17  D  2019Q4     1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
18  D  2020Q4     1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
19  D  2021Q4     1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: how can I remove values for the dummies in rows corresponding to 2018Q4? (as indicated in my desired output)

Comment: @Olive - Do you want blank or `NaN`? I think `NaN` works better so the column stays as `float`

Comment: yes NaN is good

Comment: sorry i real;ized the values are wrong. for instance, for row 1, it should be WL not LW, because A won in 2018Q4 but lost in 2019Q4.

Comment: streaks = wins.shift() + wins <== i corrected it

Comment: @not_special I updated the question, the first value of my "winner" colume by ID is NaN, when I apply your formula, for the rows corresponding to 2018Q4, I get zeros, how do i make sure i get NaNs?

Comment: @not_special, not sure why but I still get "0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0" for the second row? (2018Q4) but I want it to be NaN NaN NaN NaN since there is now value for winner for 2017Q4?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way: Use `groupby.shift` to get the previous record; then use `numpy.select` to assign values, which you use `get_dummies` to convert to dummy variables:

```py
import numpy as np
df['previous'] = df.groupby('ID')['winner'].shift()
tmp = df[['previous','winner']]
dummy_vars = ['WW','LL','WL', 'LW']
out = (df.join(pd.get_dummies(np.select([tmp.eq(1).all(1), 
                                         tmp.eq(0).all(1),
                                         tmp.eq([1,0]).all(1), 
                                         tmp.eq([0,1]).all(1)], 
                                        dummy_vars, ''))[dummy_vars+['']]
               .mask(df['previous'].isna(), ''))
       .drop(columns=['previous','']))
```

Output:

```py
   ID    date  winner WW LL WL LW
0   A  2018Q4       1            
1   A  2019Q4       0  0  0  1  0
2   A  2020Q4       0  0  1  0  0
3   A  2021Q4       1  0  0  0  1
4   B  2018Q4       1            
5   B  2019Q4       1  1  0  0  0
6   B  2020Q4       0  0  0  1  0
7   B  2021Q4       0  0  1  0  0
8   C  2018Q4       0            
9   C  2019Q4       0  0  1  0  0
10  C  2020Q4       0  0  1  0  0
11  C  2021Q4       0  0  1  0  0
12  D  2018Q4       0            
13  D  2019Q4       1  0  0  0  1
14  D  2020Q4       1  1  0  0  0
15  D  2021Q4       1  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: strangely, i get NaN for all entries for the dummies, i wonder why?

Comment: winner column is int64 and previous float64

Comment: yes, all the values for WW LL WL LW are NaNs

Comment: dtypes for WW LL WL LW is object. So i guess it has something to do with that?

Comment: yes after running all the code you indicated above. i get the four dummy columns but the values are all NaNs

Comment: @Olive what I'm saying is, run the code step-by-step. After `get_dummies` but before `join`, do you get NaNs? because your index might be different from what you presented

Comment: Oh actually, I do get values before joining!

Comment: why would index matter? I don't have any index, just a bunch of numbers but they aren't in order, because i sorted them?

Comment: @Olive join merges on index, so if the indices don’t match, it produces NaNs